# Помогите заменить функцию preg_replace() на preg_replace_callback()

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Устанавливаю форум esotalk. Выдает сообщение:

> Deprecated: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use
>   preg_replace_callback instead in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/esotalk/core/lib/ETSQLQuery.class.php on
>   line 666

Вот функция с 666 строчкой. Помогите заменить функцию preg_replace() на preg_replace_callback(). Не понимаю как это сделать.

```
public function get()
{
    // Run the appropriate get function depending on this query's mode.
    switch ($this->mode) {

        case "select":
            $query = $this->getSelect();
            break;

        case "update":
            $query = $this->getUpdate();
            break;

        case "insert":
            $query = $this->getInsert();
            break;

        case "replace":
            $query = $this->getReplace();
            break;

        case "delete":
            $query = $this->getDelete();
            break;

        case "union":
            $query = $this->getUnion();
            break;

        default:
            $query = "";
    }

    // Substitute in bound parameter values.
    $query = preg_replace('/(:[A-Za-z0-9_]+)/e', 'array_key_exists("$1", $this->parameters)
        ? ET::$database->escapeValue($this->parameters["$1"][0], $this->parameters["$1"][1])
        : "$1"', $query);

    return $query;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Модификатор `е` устарел, необходимо использовать `preg_replace_callback`, передав в качестве второго аргумента анонимную функцию обратного вызова:

```
// Substitute in bound parameter values.
$query = preg_replace_callback('/:[A-Za-z0-9_]+/', function($m) {
  return array_key_exists($m[0], $this->parameters) ? 
   ET::$database->escapeValue($this->parameters[$m[0]][0], $this->parameters[$m[0]][1]) : 
   $m[0];
}, $query);
```

**Подробности**:

- Модификатор `e` удалён
- Функция обратного вызова: `function($m) {}`
- В регулярном вырадении `'/:[A-Za-z0-9_]+/'` убраны круглые скобки за ненадобностью, так как...
- `$m[0]` представляет собой целое совпадение.